# StreamGroup.merge only retuning one stream

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm obviously misunderstanding how `StreamGroup.merge` works or how stream works or both!. I have two streams that are querying the same field in firestore. And I'm using merge to make one stream called `mergedStream`. This is used in a streamBuilder to serve up to the app.
Here's my code:

```
Stream<List<Order>> stream1({Order order})  {
    return _service.collectionStream(
        path: APIPath.orders(),
        queryBuilder: (query) =>
            query.where('orderStatus', isEqualTo: 'Pending'),
        builder: (documentSnapshot) => Order.fromFirebase(documentSnapshot));
  }

  Stream<List<Order>> stream2({Order order})  {
     return _service.collectionStream(
        path: APIPath.orders(),
        queryBuilder: (query) =>
            query.where('orderStatus', isEqualTo: 'Preparing'),
        builder: (documentSnapshot) => Order.fromFirebase(documentSnapshot));
  }
```

and the merged stream I use for my stream builder:

```
Stream<List<Order>> mergedStream() {
    final s1 = preparingStream();
    final s2 = pendingStream();
    return StreamGroup.merge([s2, s1]);
  }
```

Switching the order `[s2, s1]` changes the stream shown. And as the page loads I momentarily see the other stream but it disappears and the other stream appears..How can I merge the streams...?

EDIT: I'm adding the flutter tag because reading around it might be a [problem](https://github.com/dart-lang/async/issues/70) with `StreamBuilder`

EDIT: This has helped a bit:(link in comments, And was just a proof of concept that the streams merged) But the stream `searchResult()` doesn't update when there's a state changes in one of he streams...You have to refresh the browser. (Flutter web)

```
Stream<List<Order>> searchResult() {
    List<Stream<List<Order>>> streamList = [stream1(), stream2()];

    var x = Rx.merge(streamList).scan<List<Order>>((acc, curr,i) {
      return acc ?? <Order>[]
        ..addAll(curr);
    });
    //this test shows that the stream gets contents from both query streams
    // x.map((convert){ convert.documents.forEach((f){print(f.data["name"]);});}).listen(print);

    return x;
  }
```

Comment: just to clarify you want to have an unified stream that have a List<Order> of both s1 and s2 in one big List<Order>?

Comment: Exactly. The streams are merging. But StreamBuilder see it as 2 events. So I can't show both streams from StreamBuilder

Comment: Also having seen this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23173#issuecomment-430712769 by @GünterZöchbauer that has helped me a bit.

Comment: try mergedStream().listen((data) {
    print("DataReceived: " + data);
  });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StreamGroup.merge` merge the streams into an unified streams, but it doesn't merge the content of each one, so what you see in fact is the content of stream1 or stream2 coming one after the other.

I would recommend using [StreamZip](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamZip-class.html) which combines the contents of the 2 streams and then emmits it as a new value (The first list contains the first value emitted by each stream, the second contains the second value, and so on).

```
Stream<List<List<Order>>> mergedStream() {
    final s1 = preparingStream();
    final s2 = pendingStream();
    return StreamZip([s2, s1]);
  }
//This will give you a List with all the emmited values of each stream, in this case a List of List<Order>
```

If you want to use the package Rx I would recommend `ZipStream` or `CombineLatestStream`

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';


Stream<List<Order>> get combineList{
  final s1 = preparingStream();
  final s2 = pendingStream();
  return ZipStream.zip2<<List<Order>>, <List<Order>>, <List<Order>>>(
    s1, s2, (firstOrder, secondOrder) => <Order>[...firstOrder, ...secondOrder]); //here you combine both in a list
}
```

The difference between `Zip` and Combine is that `Zip` waits for all the inner streams to emit before doing the operation (first emmited value of s1 and first of s2, and so on) whereas `combine` doesn't care about the order, if you emit one of s1 and 3 of s2 then it will do `[s1.1, s2.1] [s1.1, s2.2]` ...

Comment: Thanks @Edwyn. Ill probably try with Rx because it returns the right type for my stream builder. `ZipStream.zip2<<List<Order>>, <List<Order>>, <List<Order>>>` This doesn't compile and I' nor sure of the syntax

Comment: are s1 and s2 Stream of type Stream<<List<Order>>? maybe because they are Stream<dynamic> because they're not casted, you could try just ZipStream.zip2(...) without the T types

Comment: s1 and s2 are of type Stream<List<Order>> not  Stream<<List<Order>. Should zip2 start with a (

Comment: Yeah got it thanks. However when one of the states of the stream changes, nothing happens unless I refresh the browser. IS this expected behaviour?

Comment: Zip only changes when both s1 and s2 changes, you better change it to CombineLatestStream.combine2 if you want it to update when one of the Streams changes

Comment: what do you mean by `zip2` in `ZipStream.zip2`. I am using it but there is no `zip2` function. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: `StreamZip` link is broken mentioned in the answer description. It is redirecting to 404 page at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/StreamZip-class.html Kindly remove or update it. Thanks.