# How to merge 2 Firestore queries streams in Flutter / Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I am trying to merge 2 `Firestore` queries to merge their snapshots/streams in `Flutter/Dart`. I have created a function for the same:

```
final _startAtTimestamp = Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.parse('2000-01-01 01:01:01.001').millisecondsSinceEpoch);

_messagesStream() {
  // message sent by logged in user
  var  streamData1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('messages')
      .where('encSenderUId', isEqualTo: _loggedInUserId)
      .where('encReceiverUId', isEqualTo: widget.encUId)
      .orderBy('sentOn', descending: false)
      .startAt([_startAtTimestamp]).snapshots();

  // message received by logged in user
  var  streamData2 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('messages')
      .where('encSenderUId', isEqualTo: widget.encUId)
      .where('encReceiverUId', isEqualTo: _loggedInUserId)
      .orderBy('sentOn', descending: false)
      .startAt([_startAtTimestamp]).snapshots();

  return StreamZip([streamData1, streamData2]);
  // return StreamGroup.merge(streamData1, streamData2);
}
```

In the build widget calling as:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: _messagesStream(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {.......
```

I have used both methods `StreamZip` and `StreamGroup.merge`. None of them work.

Kindly suggest what is the issue and how can fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: what do you get when you use `StreamGroup.merge`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Thanks for your keen interest. If I use `StreamGroup.merge([streamData1, streamData2]);` or `StreamZip([streamData1, streamData2]);` both returns same results. In other words, only second query is run and returns results.

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have noticed one important thing is that if I use `StreamGroup.merge([streamData1, streamData2]);` then returns only streamData2 query records or in vice-versa case `StreamGroup.merge([streamData2, streamData1]);` returns streamData1 query records which means last query record is returned by `StreamGroup.merge` function. Kindly check and share your suggestion to fix this very urgent issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970003/streamgroup-merge-only-retuning-one-stream

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have already checked your suggested link and posted comment on it 20 minutes ago. "what do you mean by zip2 in ZipStream.zip2. I am using it but there is no zip2 function. Any suggestion? Thanks." Any suggestion of yours regarding zip2? Thanks.

Comment: ZipStream.zip2 is part of RX dart https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart

Comment: @EdwynZN Thanks, I have used it like `ZipStream.zip2(streamData1, streamData2, (a, b){});` but still did not get any success. Getting error in console like: `type 'ZipStream<dynamic, Null>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'` Any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from ZipStream

```
ZipStream.zip2<QuerySnapshot, QuerySnapshot, List<Query DocumentSnapshot>>(streamData1, streamData2, (a, b) => [...a.docs, ...b.docs]);
```

Also wouldn't be easier to use only one snapshot? You only change the where, so maybe you could do 4 where or in to filter your data

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('messages')
      .where('encSenderUId', isEqualTo: widget.encUId)
      .where('encReceiverUId', isEqualTo: _loggedInUserId)
      .where('encSenderUId', isEqualTo: _loggedInUserId)
      .where('encReceiverUId', isEqualTo: widget.encUId)
      .orderBy('sentOn', descending: false)
      .startAt([_startAtTimestamp]).snapshots();
```

Or

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('messages')
      .where('encSenderUId', whereIn: [widget.encUId , _loggedInUserId])
      .where('encReceiverUId', isEqualTo: _loggedInUserId)
      .where('encReceiverUId', isEqualTo: widget.encUId)
      .orderBy('sentOn', descending: false)
      .startAt([_startAtTimestamp]).snapshots();
```

Comment: 1) `ZipStream.zip2......` returning an error eg. "The property 'docs' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')."

Comment: 2) all 4 where conditions will never be fulfilled that's why getting zero result.

Comment: 3) `.where('encSenderUId', whereIn: [widget.encUId , _loggedInUserId])` solution is appreciable but sorry to say, did not work for me. Giving zero result to me. Thanks a lot again, any other suggestions will be welcomed :)

Comment: For the first error I see you're using null safety, in that case `[...?a?.docs, ...?b?.docs]` should let you compile