# How do i combine or merge two stream of firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've two stream

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> s1 = users.where("uid",isNotEqualTo: "--").snapshots();
Stream<QuerySnapshot> s2 = groups.snapshots();
```

And i want single stream

```
return s1+s2;
```

I also tried StreamGroup but facing this same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970003/streamgroup-merge-only-retuning-one-stream);

Please do not send link, If you can do it via code then that will be helpful a lot.

Comment: see [CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html)

Comment: your welcome, btw, you can also use [CombineLatest](https://pub.dev/documentation/stream_transform/latest/stream_transform/CombineLatest.html) from `stream_transform` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html) is the solution.

```
CombineLatestStream<QuerySnapshot, List<QuerySnapshot>> roomStream() {
    try {
      Stream<QuerySnapshot> s1 = users.where("uid",isNotEqualTo: firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid).snapshots();
      Stream<QuerySnapshot> s2 = groupService.streamGroup();
      return CombineLatestStream.list<QuerySnapshot>([s1,s2]);
    } catch (e) {
      handleException(e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Thanks [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)